# Python avoid duplicating function call in generator

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to write `[g(acc, orig) for acc, orig in zip(itertools.accumulate(f(it)), f(it))` in one line without duplicating the call to `f`? As I understand it, I can't even use `:=` as this is a generator.

Comment: btw, I suspect you can't use `or` as a variable name.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.tee(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee). This sort of stores the intermediate values while generating (apparently in a single queue). The actual function will be called exactly once as you can see from the number of print statements below.

```
>>> def fn(x):
...   for i in range(x):
...     print("Yielding", i)
...     yield i

>>> from itertools import tee
>>> seq1, seq2 = tee(fn(10))
>>> [(acc, orig) for acc, orig in zip(accumulate(seq1), seq2)]
Yielding 0
Yielding 1
Yielding 2
Yielding 3
Yielding 4
Yielding 5
Yielding 6
Yielding 7
Yielding 8
Yielding 9
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (3, 2), (6, 3), (10, 4), (15, 5), (21, 6), (28, 7), (36, 8), (45, 9)]
```

Comment: This does solve the problem where `it` is a generator so calling `f` multiple times would lead to undesired behaviour, but I'm more so looking for a solution that solves it in one line. I'll edit the post accordingly.